# Can we configure a .NET MVC Application to not open on a particular browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, browser, web-applications

I would like my web application to open on all browsers except a particular browser(i.e when a user tries to open it on the browser).Is there a way to do that? I know it is not ideal to do that but just curious to see how we can get that done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add any framework to your project, that is capable of properly identifying User-Agent.
- On the entry point of app - detect User-Agent and thus browser.
- If it is from forbidden list - give 403 error or supply rendered views with partial, that states 'Your browser isn't supported'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request.Browser` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.browser.aspx)

Also see [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/) , you can get many other properties

```
Request.UserAgent
Request.Browser.Platform
Request.Browser.Version
Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this (possibly into a Global file)...

```
@if ((Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") && ((Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 8)))
{
    //show IE7 content
}
else
{
    //show IE8+ content 
}
```